# can't Reply to Message from twilio

Tags: sms, twilio, sms-gateway, smsmanager

I am new to Twilio API.I have trial account and I have sent Message using Twilio Rest API successfully and received message from number i.e Message as:DM-062107 and body :- Sent from your Twilio trial Account-Hello.

Now I can't able to reply this message.can any one help me to how I can reply to this and how I know that message is received.

Answer (score 5):

I have contacted to Twilio technical support for same problem and get the response. Check the reason why reply option is not enabled:

Although Twilio supports sending **outbound** messages internationally using toll-free numbers, your Indian number may not support sending **inbound** messages to US toll-free numbers. I will recommend checking with your mobile carrier to see if sending messages to US toll-free numbers is supported. If not, I will recommend using a regular US number instead of a US toll-free number and kindly retest.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio Evangelist here.

So, to reply to message you just send a normal SMS from your phone to the number. The way Twilio handles this is using a 'webhook'.

If you log into your Twilio account, click on the 'Number' tab, you'll see you have a telephone number there (the same one you sent an SMS with):

[image: Twilio Numbers Tab]

Once you've clicked on the number, you'll see a screen with some other details:

[image: Twilio Number Configuration]

Here you can configure your webhook. This is basically a URL that Twilio will send your message to. So if you configure that to point to the URL of some application you have written, you'll receive an HTTP Post or Get request (you can configure which) with the contents of the message, who it is from, etc.

You can then reply to this message with [`Twiml`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml), which is just XML:

```
<Response>
  <Message>
    This is the message that is sent in reply!
  </Message>
</Response>
```

And using this you can build up a conversation!

There are a lot of details on Twilio's website with [quick starts etc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms). [There is even a video that talks it through](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/04/get-started-with-twilio-sms-receiving-incoming-sms-quickstart.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is not what he has asked, when we are getting messages from a Twilio trial account, we cannot reply to those, Reply is not activated. Its like read only mode.

Comment: You should be able to reply to the trial number. I'm not with Twilio anymore (as an employee) but I just tried this with a new trial account and it works. Does your phone have permission to send to the Twilio number you have? Else I suggest you contact Twilio support: help@twilio.com, as something is clearly wrong. What happens when you send the SMS?

Comment: I can send messages to twilio number seperately, but as a conversation, I can't just reply to the messages I got from Twilio number.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can send an SMS to the Twilio number, so that is a reply. Can you be more explicit about what you can't do? Maybe open a new question with screenshots? I'm really struggling to understand your problem...

Comment: I dont know if the OP ever got the answer. If yes then please post it here. I am having same issue. When I receive sms from twilio, I cannot reply to it from my phone. On any other sms from any other phone, I have an option to reply but on twilio sms I don't.

Comment: Weird... I think you might want to contact help@twilio.com. The only thing I can think of is if your phone network provider doesn’t allow you to send SMS messages to that range. You should talk to the folk at Twilio directly I think...

Comment: @Learner have you got any solution

Comment: @Charnjeet Singh: I am facing same problem ...have you got any solution?

Comment: @Joyner Have you got any solution ..I am in same trouble?

Comment: @Learner,@user360321: I have posted the Twilio technical support response please see my answer why reply option not enabled. if we used the US or canada number or the number you are uisng have capability to send SMS to US number we can send else can not.

Comment: @RaghbendraNayak we cant reply from indian number. If you are sending message to US number means you can send reply from that number.